# jQuery Scroll Fires For All Classes

Tags: jquery, scroll

When I reach progress bar class by scroll down it is animated. But the bellow second progress bar is also animated. I need to animate bellow second progress bar when I reach to second progress bar by scroll.

My code is:

```js
$(window).scroll( function(){
 startAnimation();
 function startAnimation(){
  jQuery('.skills').each(function(){
   jQuery(this).find('.skillbar').animate({
    width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
   },5000);
  });
 }
});
```

```css
.skills {
 background-color:#f4f4f4;
 border-radius: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 5px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 15px 0;
}
.percent-text {
 position: relative;
 width: 50px;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: -20px;
 top: -30px;
 left: 0%;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 background-color: #333333;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 3px 5px;
}
.skillbar {
 position: relative;
 background-color:#007bff;
 border-radius: 30px;
 width: 0px;
 height: 5px;
 top: -23px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100px"></div>
<div class="skills" data-percent="90%">
 <span class="percent-text">10</span>
 <div class="skillbar"></div>  
</div><!--skills-->
<div style="height: 500px"></div>
<div class="skills" data-percent="80%">
 <span class="percent-text">10</span>
 <div class="skillbar"></div>  
</div><!--skills-->
```

Comment: `jQuery('.skills').each(...)` will, as advertised, run on each .skills element.  There's no code here that attempts to differentiate between the two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your `each` loop:

```
if ($(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
  jQuery(this).find('.skillbar').animate({
        width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
    },5000);
}
```

Here is how it works. `$(window).scrollTop()` is current scrolled position. It is equal to the height of already hidden (because of scrolling) content. Adding `$(window).height()` to it you get current lower border of what user can see. You start animation only if your skillbar is above this border.

This can also be modified to animate only bars, currently visible on the screen, excluding all above and below. This way:

```
($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop()) && ($(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()
```

Comment: Thanks it's solved. Last Day I tried a lot, but can't solve. Thanks Alex Yokisama.